# FTP directory upload , perl

Tags: perl, file, file-upload, ftp

how can I upload an entire folder to the ftp server?
I'm trying to do the following:

```
$FTP->binary();
$FTP->mkdir($pfolder);
$FTP->put("$pPath$pfolder");
```

Of course I did before authentication .. just that when I run the code, the following message appears

`Cannot open Local file C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject: Permission denied
 at projectUpload.pl line 41`

-- EDIT --

I found solution, here is the code:

```
  sub upload {
          my ( $bpath , $path , $FTP ) = @_;
          $path .= '/' unless $path =~ /\/$/;
          for my $i ( glob ( "$path*" ) ) {
                 $i =~ /(?:\/(.*))/;
                 if ( not -d $i ) {
                        if ( -f $i ) {
                               $FTP->put ( $i , $1 ) ;
                        }      
                 } else {
                        $FTP->mkdir ( $1 ) ;
                        upload ( $bpath , $i , $FTP ) if -d $i ;
                 }
          }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are using the standard `Net::FTP` module, you must upload one file at a time. There 
  are other modules, however, that allow you to upload/mirror entire directory trees.
- You probably want to go the directory you created before uploading your files. A `$FTP->cwd($pfolder);` should do the trick.
- The “Permission denied” issue is probably because `MyProject` is a directory (I guess). Locally, do a `chdir()` to that directory, open it with `opendir()`, then iterate over the files with `readdir()` and upload one file at a time.

Comment: right, but what if you have more directories inside MyProject?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to upload multiple files / directories, you may want to take a look at

```
rput ( [FlattenTree => 1] [,RemoveLocalFiles => 1] )
```

from `Net::FTP::Recursive`